# PHP MYSQL - Distinct multiple columns as one

Tags: php, mysql

I've read a lot of questions and answers related to this topic, but I can't find anything that's working for me, so I could really use some help.

I am trying to make a simple private messaging system for my website. I have a table like this:

```
private messages: id, to_id, from_id, message, time_sent
```

I am now trying to show a list on my page with the different users a member interacted with, something like Facebook messages so every name should appear only once in the list.

This is what I have now which shows me every message that I as a user ($my_id) participate in:

```
SELECT * FROM private_messages WHERE (from_id = '$Sid' AND to_id = '$my_id') OR (from_id = '$my_id' AND to_id = '$Sid')  ORDER BY time_sent ASC
```

This query shows a distincted list, but only of the people that I received a message from:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(from_id) FROM private_messages WHERE to_id='$my_id' ORDER BY time_sent DESC
```

How should I rewrite this so it gives me a distinct list of every user that I interacted with (like a list of facebook messages)? I think I need to distinct on two columns, from_id and to_id, but how should I do it?

I know the questions sounds rather vague, but I really can't explain it any better. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT IF(from_id = '$my_id', to_id, from_id) AS other_id
FROM private_messages 
WHERE '$my_id' IN (to_id, from_id) 
ORDER BY time_sent DESC
```

Comment: Isn't there missing a closing bracket? : SELECT DISTINCT(IF(from_id = '$my_id', to_id, from_id) AS other_id) FROM....

Comment: @TomK. Thanks for the remark. This was a typo. `DISTINCT` does not need any parentheses as it is not a function.

Comment: you're right, just saw that there was something missing ... you're welcome.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to give me two rows, which is what I need! Now I am trying to echo the rows based on the value of from_id and to_id. So after fetching the array, I do like this:  `if($row['from_id'] == $my_id) { echo xxxxx } elseif($row['to_id'] == $my_id) { echo xxxxxx  }`, but it's not working, it doesn't show any rows..

Comment: @SenneVandenputte The associative array fetched using my query *probably* contains a *single* index named `'other_id'`.

Comment: I tried that at first, but I was mistakenly using mysqli_fetch_array instead of mysqli_fetch_assoc. It works now, thanks for the help, you saved my day!